Divergence Constraints in Parabolic PDEs
Consider the following system of heat equations in 2D with free divergence conditions:
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial b^1}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial^2 b^1}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2 b^1}{\partial z^2} 
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial b^2}{\partial t} =   \frac{\partial^2 b^2}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2 b^2}{\partial z^2}
\end{equation}
with the divergence-free condition:
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial b^1}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial b^2}{\partial z} = 0
\end{equation}
Boundary conditions:
\begin{equation}
b^i(t, x, 0) = b^i(t, x, l_z) =b^i(t, 0,z) =b^i(t, l_x, z) = 0
\end{equation}
Initial conditions:
\begin{equation}
b^i(0, x, z) = b_0^i(x, z), \quad i = 1, 2
\end{equation}
where $i\in \{ 1,2\}$, and $t \in (0, T)$, $x \in (0, l_x)$, $z \in (0,l_z)$.
Observe that the coupling is in the divergence condition. For the sake of simplifying the system, we can use $\frac{\partial b^1}{\partial x} = -\frac{\partial b^2}{\partial z}$, we replace it in the first equation, we get for the $b^1$ equation:
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial b^1}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial^2 b^1}{\partial x^2} - \frac{\partial^2 b^2}{\partial z \partial x} 
\end{equation}
Ce can consider the term $- \frac{\partial^2 b^2}{\partial z \partial x}$ as a second member for this equation since it can be obtained from the second one. My question is:
Question: Since the new equation for $b^1$ does not involve derivatives with respect to $z$, $z$ acts as a parameter. How can the boundary conditions in $z$ be utilized?
Thank you.

You don't win anything by that substitution. A PDE is a local linear equilibrium condition between inertial forces $\partial_t$  and a local stress tensor in $d\vec b, d \vec x$.  You only exchange the  $dz$ for the $db_2$ directions in the 4-d local tangent space, that now acts as an inhomogenous external force crosswise.
